# Child items grow the container instead of overflow

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

guys. I'm a total noob when it comes to web design. I know that I'm kind of over using `flex`. But!! It's so easy with them.

Anyway, my issue is that one of my component (using TailwindCSS and React) is a Infinite Loading List, but the thing is that the element in the list are growing the container even do it has `overflow: auto`. I have been tearing my head apart.

[image: Error]

I have set the container's background in a dark color so the problem could be understood faster. If you want to see the code itself it's on https://pastebin.com/Vhuxii6j

I really don't know what else to do. I have tried to put `flex-shrink` in the container so it would not grow, but it does nothing. I have tried putting the child elements as `inline-flex`, nothing.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try setting a width to auto / 100% / Inherit (Only if you have set the custom Parent width) that should fix it

Comment: My problem is with the height, not the width. But, I did it anyway and that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a good night sleep and a work day. I managed to fix it with two simple class `flex-1` and `min-h-0` from TailwindCSS. This were added to the list's parent

Thanks to @Nishant Sham Vispute for trying :)
Maybe you can use this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the Issue
Here is what you need to do, on the scroll list you will need to change `overflow-auto` to
`overflow-y-scroll` and also add `max-h-#` where # is any of the preset number from the tailwind here is the [link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/max-height#class-reference) for the doc i refered to

I have attached [link](https://codepen.io/nvispute/pen/RwGXRrx) to the solution for the output where i set the `max-h-80`
This show that the issue is with the auto height inheritance. for which you may have to retink your base layout

NOTE - You may have to change the view on the codepen.io link and bring the result at bottom incase if it doesnt open it in that layout.

Comment: This does work, but I don't want the list just taking a portion of his parent's height. I want it to fill the parent height but also to not over fill if that make sense